# Is it acceptable to use "almost" at the end of a sentence to make it sound dramatic?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence, sentence-patterns, sentence-starts

Does adding the word "almost" at the end of the sentence make it sound dramatic or does it change the context of the sentence? Additionally, is it grammatically acceptable?

- This new laptop has depleted my savings, almost.
- She gives him a slap on the wrist, almost.
- This new house has depleted my savings, well almost.

Comment: Very informal. Perhaps okay in dialogue in a novel about a young person.

Comment: I think *almost* softens the previous phrase.  It removes drama.  Instead of your savings being gone (a very dramatic condition) it's just almost gone- so not as bad as all gone.

Comment: “Almost” means “nearly”; it is not an intensifier. Whether it heightens drama depends on how it is used. I expect it would take a very skilled writer to pull it off, though.

Comment: "This new laptop has depleted my savings, almost" and "This new house has depleted my savings ... well almost" I'd take as being mitigator usage added as an afterthought and/or concession, rather than a dramatiser. Common in everyday conversation. //  "She gives him a slap on the wrist, almost" sounds pretentious or clumsy; compare _I like Rhy_'s "I won a free plane trip and VIP pass for the theme parks in Disneyland, almost" etc.

Comment: I don't understand the second example. If you almost got a slap on the wrist then you didn't get one so what actually did happen in that case?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this question is that it is difficult to support an answer to the first part with any objective evidence, and “is it acceptable” always begs the question “by whom?”. However:

1. As a British native speaker I would regard this as a *self-depreciatory admission of exaggeration*. It makes it less, rather than more dramatic — Being hard up as less dramatic than being penniless, although the exaggerated style of the dialogue itself is dramatic. Asking whether it could change the “Context of the sentence” seems strange. It says nothing about the context (which we do not know from the examples), only the meaning.
2. I’m no grammarian (and I should refuse to answer two questions in one anyway) but it strikes me that as a speech pattern it is in effect two sentences, the second missing a verb: “, almost.” standing in place of “. Well, I almost did.”. It would be generally accepted in speech. In writing it would depend on the style you were after. Obviously it works in reported speech, but an author aiming for a particular narrative style might use it, perhaps in an account of difficult day, e.g.

> And so I went to pick up the kids from school, and Sue had got paint all over her dress, and then when we stopped at the supermarket they were out of Tom’s favourite breakfast cereal, and he started wailing, and my mother called me on the mobile tell me the dog had been sick on the carpet. There and then I had a nervous breakdown. **Almost**.

This (invented) fragment also illustrates the use as a stylistic device: the single word “almost” contrasts with the long concatenated sentence, and brings the section of the narrative to an end. Whether or not they like the style, nobody is going to criticize it as ungrammatical.

The moral is probably that if you understand the rules of the language you know when and how you can break them. If you don’t, they’ll break you. Almost.

Answer (score 0):

**Use *drama* + *negation* for contrast**

This kind of construction is gramatically fine, but it will work *only* if the situation described in the first part of your sentence is *specific, dramatic, or outlandish.* The ‘almost’ then modifies it. The effect is dramatic - you’re saying ‘this - nearly happened!’. Which of course, it... actually, didn’t! But that’s drama, innit?

This construction doesn’t work where the first part is already rather... dilute or milque-toast, or is a range.

Revised examples that could work:

- This new laptop has bankrupted me, almost!
- She slapped his face, almost!
- This new house has made me into a pauper, almost!

*Dramatise* - ie ramp up and exaggerate - the first part of the sentence to make it exciting, *then* use ‘almost!’ to knock it down again - to reassure the reader that... you just made that up, for effect.  But that what you are conveying, is the *drama* - the stress and the emotion - that these events evoked.

To analyse your examples further:

- This new laptop has depleted my savings, almost

Means ‘this new laptop has made my savings go down a little bit - but not really’.  Where’s the drama in that? It’s not much of a ‘story’ is it?

- She gives him a slap on the wrist - almost

Means ‘she gives him a mild reprimand - oh but not really’ again, it’s hardly compelling.

- This new house has depleted my savings, well almost

Means ‘this new house has caused my savings to go down a bit - but not really’ - again, there’s not much being said here.

So - *dramatise first* - so that the ‘almost’ has something much bigger *to contrast with.*

Here’s what I consider to be a better example:

‘Two children, a bi-polar husband, a mortgage, and caring for a sick mother-in-law brought this once powerful businesswoman to the edge of suicide - almost’.

Note how I layered on the ‘bad stuff’, contrasted to ‘what she was before’ - a businesswoman - to make a big contrast to what she became ‘ a suicide risk - almost!

So then, you’ve taken us to the brink -eek! Suicide! We’ve peeped over (but not yet toppled) and now presumably the story will go on to outline her various trials and tribulations- and how she overcame them - thus avoiding the ‘imagined, dramatic’ possible outcome - that we’d actually artistically made up - to make the story exciting and enticing.

You’ll see this below in a story about a woman who ‘almost died!’ After being scratched by a cat in her garden.

*Exciting story - almost?*

https://www.msn.com/en-au/news/world/mother-reveals-how-she-almost-died-after-she-was-scratched-by-a-stray-cat-in-her-garden/ar-AAEEjoH

Comment: I agree that 'almost' at the end reduces the dramatic impact. It seems to me that the construction is similar to adding 'not' at the end of the sentence as in "This is a great party, not!"

Comment: Yes, @BoldBen - and the more fabulous the phrase, the greater the contrast of ‘not’. For example, ‘it was a glittering evening of trapeze artists, champagne, and caviar - not!

Answer (score -1):

In a story or any kind of fiction  - **Yes, it does.**

The usage of the word 'almost' at the end of the sentence/quote adds 'uncertainty' to a sentence, and uncertainty is a trait and hence provides the context an emotion (like: sarcasm, irony, satire etc.) and thus, created mild drama.

Comment: Why do you limit this to a “story or any kind of fiction”? Why does it not apply to any other communication, eg a news report, or normal conversation, or non-fiction?

Comment: I mean if you wanna look dramatic or a bit humourous you can use it anywhere. But it's a thing fiction writers use profusely.

Comment: Citation needed!

Answer (score -1):

It makes you sound like a stereotypically depressed emo, therefore "anti-dramatic"

No offence but here's some context as to why,

I went in a running race and came first, almost

I won a free plane trip and VIP pass for the theme parks in Disneyland, almost

I've gotten a brand new suit which I took to wear at a high profile party in the inner city of new York and got to host a three course banquet for the former president of Uganda, almost